# Не отслеживается OnClick на кастомном диалоге

Tags: android, java

Вывел кастомный диалог в отдельный класс, на нем разместил некую кнопочку, теперь из класса этого диалога не могу отловить нажатие. В `OnClick` прописал `onClickPlayStop`.

```
public void onClickPlayStop(Dialog dialog) {
//код// 
};
```

лог говорит, что не найден метод **onClickPlayStop**.

Comment: Приведите пожалуйста код класса диалога и код там где используете слушатель события.

Answer (score 2):

По приведенному коду трудно что-либо сказать, возможно вы не создали и не заимплементили свой уникальный интерфейс `OnClickPlayStopListener`.